# Custom Post Type not working with Capabilities

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I have the following custom post type that I am using on one of my sites:

```
function careers_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Careers', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Career', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent career:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View career', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New career', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New career', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit career', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update career', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No careers found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No careers found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'career', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'career information pages', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'career', $args );

}
```

The sucker works beautifully. However I want to add a custom capability to it. I used this tutorial: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types Once I make the code this, it stops working:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function careers_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Careers', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Career', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent career:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View career', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New career', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New career', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit career', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update career', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No careers found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No careers found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'career', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'career information pages', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type' => 'career_editor',
        'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_career',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_career',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_career',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_career',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_career',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_career',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_career',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_career',
            'read_post' => 'read_career',
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'career', $args );

}
```

I even tried taking the capabilities array out and the content type still vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check to make sure your user role has those new capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

`'capability_type'` is an argument that must be a valid **post type**.

So, or you use one of default post types (post, page) or once you have defined your own capabilities array you have to use your own post type.

So, using:

```
....
'capability_type' => 'career'
....
```

your code should work.

However, once you defined all the capability it should work also without setting any `'capability_type'` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the capabilites to some existing role or add you own user role.

For example:

```
    add_role('career_editor', 'Carreer Editor', array (
        'publish_career'        => true,
        'edit_career'           => true,
        'edit_others_careerr'   => true,
        'delete_career'         => true,
        'delete_others_career'  => true,
        'read_career'           => true,
        'edit_career'           => true,
        'delete_career'         => true,
        'read_career'           => true,
        'read_private_carreer'  => true,
        'read'                  => true,
   ));
```

Now we have a new user role, `career_editor`, with assgined custom capabilites of our custom post type. Now you must have a user with the role `career_editor` assigned.